# how to configure hibernate with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Getting below error on using hibernate configuration

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
```

Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.

This is the Application.java file that I am using

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The properties file -

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = 
org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 4):

You have Excluded the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` that means you have to manually specify a `@Bean` for `DataSource`. The DataSource configuration in `application.properties` will not be loaded because of the exclusion.

Comment: I have tried by removing that from exclude but still getting same error. Do I  need to specify DataSource for this by default?